# A problem about Taylor polynomial approximation

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)=\frac {e^x-1}{x}$ when $x\neq 0$, $f(x)=1$ when $x=0$.
>
> (a) Compute the n-th Tylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$, $f^{(k)}(0)$ for any $k\in \{0\}\bigcup\mathbb N$, and the remainder $R_{n,0,f}$.
>
> (b) Compute $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ with an error less than $10^{-4}$.

For (a), I found that f is equal to both $\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}\frac {x^{k-1}}{k!}$ and $\sum^{n+2}_{x=1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}$ up to order $n$ at $0$ but they are different polynomials. But according to my textbook they should be exactly the same polynomial. And, I cannot figure out a way to compute the remainder. The only formula I can come up with is $R_{n,0,f}=\int^{x}_{0}\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt$. I don't want to calculate derivatives of $f$ directly so I don't know how to calculate the remainder.

For(b), define $F(x)=\int^{x}_0f(x)dx$. Then by Taylor's theorem, for a given natural number $n\in\mathbb N$, $$F(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=0}\frac{F^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i+\int^{x}_0\frac{F^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{F^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i+\int^{x}_0\frac{F^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt$$, since $F^{(i)}=f^{(i-1)}$ for any $1\leq i$, we have $$F(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{f^{(i-1)}(0)}{i!}x^i+\int^{x}_0\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt$$. If we could restrict remainder term $\int^{x}_0\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^ndt$, then we will be able to choose a propriate $n$ in order to calculate the integral within the range.

Comment: My eyes hurt.... \displaystyle??

Comment: Ugh... this is like reading Euler. And not in a good way...

Answer (score 0):

you can go from the macularin series for $e^x.$ that gives you 
$$\begin{align}e^x - 1 &= \int_0^x e^t \, dt\\
&=(t-x)e^t\big|_0^x-\int_0^x (t-x)e^t\, dt\\
&=x-\int_0^x (t-x)e^t\, dt \tag 1\\
&=x-\frac 12(t-x)^2e^t\big|_0^x+\int_0^x\frac 12(t-x)^2 e^t\, dt\\
&=x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+\int_0^x\frac 12(t-x)^2 e^t\, dt \tag 2\\
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{e^x - 1}x = 1+\frac x{2!} + \frac {x^2}{3!} + \cdots +\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} + (-1)^n \frac 1 {xn!}\int_0^x(t-x)^ne^t\, dt$$

when $x$ is away from zero, the remainder $$ (-1)^n \frac 1 {xn!}\int_0^x(t-x)^ne^t\, dt $$ looks alright. i don't know how to handle when $x$ is close to zero.

Comment: how can you restrict the remainder term?

Comment: you mean bound the remainder for a a fixed $x \ne 0?$

Comment: Yes, specifically for $x=1$

Comment: you can use the mean value theorem for the integrals. that will give you $R_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\int_0^1 (t-1)^n e^t \, dt = \frac1{(n+1)!}e^c \frac{1}{(n+2)} < \frac e{(n+2)!}$

Comment: Your formula can be improved.

Comment: how/what do you mean?